# BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'HTML_ENTITIES

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have recently upgrade BeautifulSoup from version 3.0 to version 4.1 on a Windows machine.

I am now getting a strange error:

```
File "C:\path\to\myscript.py", line 23
0, in soupify
    return BeautifulSoup(html, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'HTML_ENTITIES'
```

Here is the snippet of code that causes the exception to be thrown:

```
def soupify(html):
    return BeautifulSoup(html, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
```

The doc for BS does not mention how the constructor signature has changed fro v3 to v4. How may I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> An incoming HTML or XML entity is always converted into the
>   corresponding Unicode character. Beautiful Soup 3 had a number of
>   overlapping ways of dealing with entities, which have been removed.
>   **The BeautifulSoup constructor no longer recognizes the smartQuotesTo
>   or convertEntities arguments.** (Unicode, Dammit still has
>   smart_quotes_to, but its default is now to turn smart quotes into
>   Unicode.)
>
> If you want to turn those Unicode characters back into HTML entities
>   on output, rather than turning them into UTF-8 characters, you need to
>   use an [output formatter](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters).

Source: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#entities

Answer (score 0):

Theron's answer is probably the best but, make sure the namespaces aren't being fiddled with. If I'm remembering correctly, `HTML_ENTITIES` is part of the `BeautifulStoneSoup` namespace and not the `BS` one. It looks like you've done `from BeatifulSoup import *` due to the way you call `BeautifulSoup(html, etc)` without referring to the module it comes from.

So try `return BeautifulSoup(html, convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)` and see if that works.

Comment: In BS3 those constants were defined in BeautifulStoneSoup, but BeautifulSoup subclassed BeautifulStoneSoup so BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES did work.I removed those constants because they configured a feature--converting some but not all entities to Unicode characters--that no longer exists. The BeautifulStoneSoup class itself has been deprecated; now you write BeautifulSoup(markup, "xml").

Answer (score 0):

You're importing BeautifulSoup, wrong. Insteal of doing:

```
from BeautifulSoup import *
```

Just do:

```
 import BeautifulSoup
```