# python - struggling with string encoding and accented quotes/apostrophes

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

I have a simple RSS feed script that takes the contents of each article and runs it through some simple processing before saving it in a database.

The problem is, after running the text through the following all accented apostrophes and quotes are stripped from the text.

```
# this is just an example string, I use feed_parser to download the feeds
string = """&#160; <p>This is a sentence. This is a sentence. I'm a programmer. I&#8217;m a programmer, however I don&#8217;t graphic design.</p>"""

text = BeautifulSoup(string)
# does some simple soup processing

string = text.renderContents()
string = string.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
string = string.replace('<html>','')
string = string.replace('</html>','')
string = string.replace('<body>','')
string = string.replace('</body>','')
string = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', string).encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
print "".join([x for x in string if ord(x)<128])
```

Which results in:

```
> <p>  </p><p>This is a sentence. This is a sentence. I'm a programmer. Im a programmer, however I dont graphic design.</p>
```

All the html entity quotes/apostrophes are stripped out. How do I fix this?

Comment: You really want to use the [`feedparser` library](https://code.google.com/p/feedparser/) when handling RSS feeds. It'll clean up most of your feeditems for you without the need to manually replace tags (which can be done in a different way).

Comment: The things that strips them out is BeautifulSoup. This is probably by design. Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish by using it?

Comment: The sample code doesn't work for me as `BeautifulSoup` doesn't expand `&#NNNN;` escapes.

Comment: I use BeautifulSoup for ease of processing links in the html text, things like stripping out onclick/target/rel/style as well as checking the href tag for other validations.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me, you probably missed the `convertEntities` argument of the  `BeautifulSoup` constructor :

```
string = """&#160; <p>This is a sentence. This is a sentence. I'm a programmer. I&#8217;m a programmer, however I don&#8217;t graphic design.</p>"""

text = BeautifulSoup(string, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES) # See the converEntities argument
# does some simple soup processing

string = text.renderContents()
string = string.decode('utf-8')
string = string.replace('<html>','')
string = string.replace('</html>','')
string = string.replace('<body>','')
string = string.replace('</body>','')
# I don't know why your are doing this
#string = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', string).encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
print string
```

Comment: I ran you suggestion and it turns out convertEntities was actually depreciated (I'm using BS4), after some more googling around I came across output formatters and another solution which will probably work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856011/beautifulsoup-has-no-attribute-html-entities