# Converting from old BeautifulSoup format to the new

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I found an older Python code, which has this line in it:

```
    return BeautifulSoup(m.group(1),
            convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES).contents[0].string
```

When i try to run the code i get this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'HTML_ENTITIES
```

Can someone please explain what is the meaning of the line:

```
BeautifulSoup(m.group(1),convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES).contents[0].string
```

And how this can be done in the new version using formater?

I know that there has been a question similar to this answered here:
[BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'HTML_ENTITIES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856011/beautifulsoup-has-no-attribute-html-entities)
but as I am not familiar with BeautifulSoup, I couldn't convert the line to new format.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify `convertEntities` at all here, that behaviour (converting HTML entities to their Unicode codepoints) is now the *default*.

Comment: So can you please write what the code should look like in new version of BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Just drop the convertEntities kwargs, I.E., BeautifulSoup(m.group(1)).contents[0].string